# R Shiny - Popup window when hovering over icon

Tags: r, shiny, popup, hover

I would like to simply add a hovering window over an icon after a simple line of text.
I have found the shinyBS package, which seems to make this possible but it is linked to shiny outputs.
Having something like the code below in the "ui" of the shiny app makes the buttons work but  they are linked to the radioButtons in this case.

```
CVI <- c("Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3")
CNI <- c("Peter1", "Peter2", "Peter3")
    
radioButtons(inputId = "Attribute",  label="Attribute", choiceValues = CVI,
               

             choiceNames = list(
                                tagList(
                                        tags$span(CNI[1]), #DoS
                                        tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "1_info", style = "color: gray;")
                                             ), 
                                tagList(
                                        tags$span(CNI[2]), #DoO
                                        tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "2_info", style = "color: gray;")
                                                         ), 
                                tagList(
                                        tags$span(CNI[3]), #Ratio
                                        tags$span(icon("info-circle"), id = "3_info", style = "color: gray;")
                                                         ))
                                      ),# radiobuttons end
                        
  Popover buttons
   bsPopover(id="1_info", title=NULL, content="Test1", trigger="hover", placement="right", options=list(container="body")),
   bsPopover(id="2_info", title=NULL, content="Test2", trigger="hover", placement="right", options=list(container="body")),
   bsPopover(id="3_info", title=NULL, content="Test3", trigger="hover", placement="right", options=list(container="body"))
```

How can I achieve something similar but without the radioButtons, simply like the word "Example" and then an icon where I hover and get a popup with some information (see picture).

[image: Example popup]

I would create it somewhat like this:

```
Example_Text <- "Example_text" # This is what comes in the popup
"Example", span(icon("info-circle"), id = "Example_Popup", style = "color: gray;")
```

Comment: An non-elegant way would be to create a tooltip with a div.
tags$div(title=Example_Text ,span(icon("info-circle"), id = "Example_Popup", style = "color: gray;"))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native HTML tooltips are not customizable. [Bootstrap tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) are.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

css <- '
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #73AD21;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.tooltip > .arrow::before {
  border-right-color: #73AD21;
}
'

js <- "
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip()
})
"

shinyApp(
  server = function(input,output,session){},
  ui = fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 4),
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(css)),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    br(),
    span(
      "Example",
      span(
        `data-toggle` = "tooltip", `data-placement` = "right",
        title = "A tooltip",
        icon("info-circle")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: this is great, thank you so much! 
Just a few more things: for some reason the arrow always stays black for me, with what commands can I adjust the colors to style the whole window like in my example?
The text I use in the box is a bit longer and thus it extends quite far horizontally. This becomes an issue because the tooltip box appears to be restricted in size by the column I use in my shiny app. Is there any way to make the tooltip ignore such restrictions?

Comment: Hi Stéphane, great resource, thanks. Any ideas on how to apply different styles to different tooltip boxes around the app based on this approach? Here's a question I just posted about that in case you have an input: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75515925/12372421.

Comment: Stéphane, do you think it will be possible to have an HTML code constituting the tootltip text? I need something like: `"Click the pin icon [i] and then..."`, where `[i]` is an image imported through the following HTML: `<img src="./assets/marker.png">`

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with `div(title=, style=, ...)`.

```r
shinyApp(
  server = function(input,output,session){},
  ui = fluidPage(
    span(
      "Example",
      div(style = "display:inline-block;",
          title = "A tooltip",
          icon("info-circle")))
  )
)
```

Pause your mouse over the icon and you'll see `A tooltip`. It isn't styled like the directional callout you have in your page, perhaps it's sufficient.

Comment: It works but it isn't ideal. Is there any way to modify the popup window? Like changing font color, window width, time until it shows up?

Comment: You can add whatever CSS you need to `div(style="...", ...)`.