# How to use bslib package pop up window inside a table rendered with rhandsontable in R Shiny?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, bslib

In the code at the bottom I am trying to follow the template used in [R Shiny - Popup window when hovering over icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73306444/r-shiny-popup-window-when-hovering-over-icon), the Laurent answer, and am trying to pull it into a rhandsontable table. I simply want to render the popup window as shown in the image below. Why does my code not work?

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

css <- '
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #73AD21;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.tooltip > .arrow::before {
  border-right-color: #73AD21;
}
'

js <- "
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip()
})
"
ui = fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css)),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('my_table')
)

server = function(input,output,session){
  DF = data.frame(
    Col_1 = c("This is row 1","This is row 2"), 
    Col_Help = c(
      as.character(
        span(
          "Example",
          span(
            `data-toggle` = "tooltip", `data-placement` = "right",
            title = "A tooltip",
            icon("info-circle")
          )
        )
      ),
      as.character(
        span(
          "Example",
          span(
            `data-toggle` = "tooltip", `data-placement` = "right",
            title = "A tooltip",
            icon("info-circle")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    text = c("Row 1 does xxx","Row 2 does yyy"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
  output$my_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable::rhandsontable(
      DF
    ) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = c(200, 80)) %>%
      hot_col(1:2, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer")) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = ifelse(names(DF) != "text", 100, 0.1))
  })
  
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `allowedTags` to mark which `HTML` tags should be rendered by the `safeHTMLRenderer`.

A small nuisance is that the `icon` is not rendered properly unless you add the `fontawesome::fa_html_dependency` manually. My guess is that because of the special way `handsontable` is rendering its content, the necessary dependencies for the `fontawesome` icons are not properly loaded.

Finally, again because of rendering reasons, you have to call `.tooltip` once the content is rendered, which is apparently not the case when the DOM is ready. Thus, you should use `htmlwidgets::onRender` instead of `$()`.

Having said this, here is an example which does what you eant:

```r
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

css <- '
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #73AD21;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.tooltip > .arrow::before {
  border-right-color: #73AD21;
}
'

ui = fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css)),
    fontawesome::fa_html_dependency(),
  ),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('my_table')
)

server = function(input,output,session){
  DF = data.frame(
    Col_1 = c("This is row 1","This is row 2"), 
    Col_Help = c(
      as.character(
        span(
          "Example",
          span(
            `data-toggle` = "tooltip", `data-placement` = "right",
            title = "A tooltip",
            icon("info-circle")
          )
        )
      ),
      as.character(
        span(
          "Example",
          span(
            `data-toggle` = "tooltip", `data-placement` = "right",
            title = "A tooltip",
            icon("info-circle")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    text = c("Row 1 does xxx","Row 2 does yyy"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  output$my_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable::rhandsontable(
      DF, allowedTags = "<span><i>"
    ) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = c(200, 80)) %>%
      hot_col(1:2, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer")) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = ifelse(names(DF) != "text", 100, 0.1)) %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("function() {$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip()}")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Works great thothal! For this sort of thing, would you recommend shinyBS instead? This takes a lot of CSS/html