# R Shiny - Multiple onHover popups each with different CSS style

Tags: css, r, shiny, popup, hover

### Context

I'm trying to get tooltip popups in different sections of an app, and want their style (font, background, ...) be different from one section to the other. For instance, in one section the popup background is blue and in another section it is red.

So far I've borrowed from [this SO accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73325271/12372421), which works great for a single CSS style. However, I haven't been able to extend it to define different styles and have them applied to different tooltips around the app.

Not sure if I'm understanding well the flow because I'm not quite experienced in CSS and JS, but based on a few tests I've done changing the 'tootlip' name by something arbitrary like 'myTooltip' in different parts of the code, I think the 'tooltip' element the CSS code is referring to comes from the '.tooltip()' call in the JSS function. If that is the case, and the name of the CSS-edited container comes from the name of the involved JSS function, I don't see how I could define variations of that CSS for different sections of the app.

---

### An MRE of my code so far

**CSS file:** `style.css`

```
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #2355b4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

**JS file:** `dynam.js`

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip()
})
```

**R Shiny file:** `myApp.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 4),
    includeCSS("style.css"),
    includeScript("dynam.js"),
    br(),br(),
    span(
      "Example 1 (I want this tooltip blue)",
      span(
        `data-toggle` = "tooltip",
        `data-placement` = "right",
        title = "A tooltip",
        icon("info-circle")
      )
    ),
    br(),br(),br(),
    span(
      "Example 2 (I want this tooltip red)",
      span(
        `data-toggle` = "tooltip",
        `data-placement` = "right",
        title = "A tooltip",
        icon("info-circle")
      )
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, server, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,
         options = list(display.mode = "normal"),
         enableBookmarking = "server")
```

**Result on hover**:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with Bootstrap 3 (the default in Shiny). You have to use CSS classes (here `TOOLTIP1` and `TOOLTIP2`). But I have been unable to set a color to the arrow (this works with Bootstrap 4).

[image]

```r
library(shiny)

css <- '
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.TOOLTIP1 + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #73AD21;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.TOOLTIP1 + .tooltip > .arrow::before {
  border-color: #73AD21;
}
.TOOLTIP2 + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #933337;
  color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.TOOLTIP2 + .tooltip > .arrow::before {
  border-bottom-color: #933337;
}
'

js <- "
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip()
})
"

shinyApp(
  server = function(input,output,session){},
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(css)),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    ),
    br(),
    span(
      "Example 1 ",
      span(
        class = "TOOLTIP1",
        `data-toggle` = "tooltip", `data-placement` = "right",
        title = "A tooltip",
        icon("info-circle")
      )
    ),
    br(),
    span(
      "Example 2 ",
      span(
        class = "TOOLTIP2",
        `data-toggle` = "tooltip", `data-placement` = "bottom",
        title = "Another tooltip",
        icon("info-circle")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

---

## EDIT

I've finally found how to color the arrow:

```css
.TOOLTIP1 + .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow {
  border-right-color: #73AD21;
}
.TOOLTIP2 + .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #933337;
}
```